# Dynamic boundaries for FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

As documented

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, xs, min, max}]
```

searches for a solution, stopping the search if `x` ever gets outside the range `min` to `max` and returning the error `FindRoot::reged`.

Now I have

```
FindRoot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {{x, xs}, {y, ys}}]
```

and I want to obtain the same behavior but for the constrain `x > y`.

Is this possible?

In particular, I'm interested in the case in which there are many solutions that satisfy the constrain, and I want to get as many as possible of them by giving several starting points.

Comment: Can you please give examples of `f` and `g`. Is there always (one, many, infinite?) solution(s) for `x>y`? Do you need one/many/all of them? Your problem is too general the way it is posed. In any case, perhaps it might be of help that you can restrict evaluating your functions in certain domains like so `f[x_, y_] /; (x > y) := Sin[x y] ;` If you `Plot3D` you'll see it's only evaluated for `x>y`. This wouldn't help very much here as `FindRoot` will spit out an error every time the function is not defined but it's a start.

Comment: @gpap Rather than *restrict* the functions, as you suggest, perhaps you could *redefine* the functions via reflection. That way you could simply recover the correct value by re-reflection, if necessary.

Comment: Making these changes I lose continuity or differentiability in my functions, I wonder how that can affect the behavior of FindRoot (if any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic pattern is this:

```
Module[{findRootTag},
  Catch[FindRoot[{x^2 + y^2, x}, {x, 5}, {y, 2},
      StepMonitor :> If[x <= y, Throw[$Failed, findRootTag]]],
    findRootTag]]
```

A more complex example:

```
Module[{f, g, cond, sol, pts, findRootTag},
 {f, g} = {x^2 + y^2 - 1, x - 2 y^2};
 cond = x <= y;
 {sol, {pts}} = Reap@Catch[FindRoot[{f, g}, {x, 1.8}, {y, 1.5},
     StepMonitor :> If[cond, Throw[$Failed, findRootTag], Sow[{x, y}]],
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]], findRootTag];
 Show[
  RegionPlot[cond, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> LightRed],
  ContourPlot[{f == 0, g == 0}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, ContourStyle -> Blue],
  Graphics[{Gray, Line[pts], Black, Point[pts], Red, Text[Style["Stay out!", 24], {.5, 1.5}]}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> sol]]
```

[image]

Try changing the condition (`cond`) to something else, like `x + y < 2`.
Then `sol` should become `$Failed`.

[image]

Comment: I would like to receive the message with `Check`, how can I obtain that?

Comment: Do you mean this: define `FindRoot::outside = "A step fell out of the allowed region."` and then `Check[FindRoot[..., StepMonitor :> If[x<y, Message[FindRoot::outside]], ...], $Failed]`? However, the main problem is that you cannot _interrupt_ `FindRoot` but with `Throw`.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mean. Then, as I use all this in a `Table`, how can I use `Throw` to bring back nothing, when the condition is not met? (I mean not adding any item to the list, not to add the item `NULL`!)

Comment: You have many choices to accomplish that: `Table[If[EvenQ[i], i], {i, 7}] /. Null -> Sequence[]`, or `Table[If[EvenQ[i], i, Unevaluated@Sequence[]], {i, 7}]`, or using `Reap`/`Sow` again.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But If I want that `Throw` returns a `Rule` for `x` and `y`, how can I obtain that? If I simply write `Throw[{x->q,y->p}]`, it replaces for `x` and `y` the last computed values, so instead of `x->q` I obtain something like `2.34->q`.

Comment: This is a bit tricky indeed. What you could do is `Throw[With[{tmpx = x}, Hold@{x -> tmpx}], findRootTag]` and then `ReleaseHold` it after it has been `Catch`ed.

Comment: Note that `ReleaseHold` is best inserted inside `Catch`: `Catch[FindRoot[...], findRootTag, ReleaseHold[#1]&]` instead of `ReleaseHold@Catch[...]`. You can study the difference between the two constructs with the following simple four examples: `wrapper@Catch[a; b; c, _]`,
`wrapper@Catch[a; Throw[b, tag]; c, _]`,
`Catch[a; b; c, _, wrapper]`,
`Catch[a; Throw[b, tag]; c, _, wrapper]`.